# code first cascade delete in config

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Is there anyway to cascade delete false in the entity framework config settings. For now I have done using fluent API but there are multiple place where cascade delete need to be set false, so is there any single point where I can set for all classes, as I don't have any need of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); 

        //Set cascade options here also
    }
```